# i am finding all words that have five letters in a vector of strings with equal_range and it keeps throwing an error saying it isnt sorted

Tags: c++, stl

```
void Iterator::displayStringFour(const vector<string> &v)
{
    vector<string>tempVect(v.size());
    tempVect = v;
    int smallest;

    sort(tempVect.begin(), tempVect.end(), Equal());
```

> In the line above I sort the vector in order of least chars in a string to greatest.

```
    pair<vector<string>::iterator,vector<string>::iterator> equalRange;
```

> **this next line is where it throws an error saying that the set
>   isnt sorted. i have used
>            a functor object to sort in in order of least chars to greatest and i am not sure how else     it would like for me to sort
>   the vector **

```
    equalRange = equal_range(tempVect.begin(),tempVect.end(),"-----");
    vector<string>::iterator range = equalRange.first;

    while(range!=equalRange.second)
    {
        cout<<*range;
        ++range;
    }
}
```

> This is my functor object that takes two strings and sorts the vector

```
class Equal
{
public:
    bool operator()(string a,string b)
    {
        return a.length()<b.length();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass Equal() to equal_range as fourth argument, otherwise it will use the default compare functor, which is 'less'.